# What is "er 'n"?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

I came across this sentence in Der Spiegel:

> "Er lebt auf großem Fuß, der Boss vom Bosporus. Bei Pressefreiheit kriegt er 'n Hals, drum braucht er viele Schals", singt eine Männerstimme zur Melodie von Nenas "Irgendwie, irgendwo, irgendwann".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the abbreviation of "er einen", i.e. in the example sentence "kriegt er einen Hals".

("Einen Hals kriegen" can be translated as "to get very upset about/angry at someone/something")

Comment: but 'n is the wrong abbreviation for einen... 'nen is the right one. 'ne is eine and 'n is ein. Willst'ne Birne? Ich hab so'nen Abend schonmal erlebt. 'N Affe hatte mich gebissen...

Comment: @Armin, *einen* can be pronounced with the *e* elided, which essentially leaves a slightly longer *n*. (The second part may be controversial, i.e. nonsense that I made up.)

Comment: @CarstenS I think it sounds totally weird, when the e is missing...

Comment: @Armin Das ist doch Text zum Lied, und _'nen_ würde nicht so gut zur Melodie passen...

Comment: Es gibt da vielleicht regionale Unterschiede, aber in meinem Dialekt (Mitte NRW) ist *'n* für *einen* auch außerhalb von Liedtexten üblich.

Comment: 'n == 'nen - Nur nochmal verkürzt, für extrem Sparsame ;)

Comment: @tofro Gilt aber nur in die eine Richtung. *Nen* anstelle von *n* irritiert mich immer wieder ;)